# How to add a test set to a test execution with Jira Rest API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I'm trying to add a test set to an existing test execution in Jira and I found in this [documentation](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Test+Executions+-+REST) link how to associate a test to a test execution but still I didn't know how to use it.

It's confusing the request to view the tests of a test execution is the same as the request to add a test set to a test execution. Also where do I put the test key that I want to add to the test execution.

Can someone help me on how to call that request?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API call accepts both Test or Test Set issue keys.

If you click on the arrow next to the API endpoint you can see an example using "curl".

[image: Xray REST API Test Execution endpoint]

Note that Test Executions only contain references to Tests; even though you can refer to Test Sets, what you'll be doing is "adding the tests contained in the given test sets".

Let me share also an [open-source postman collection](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-postman-collections) that shows concrete REST API examples, including on how to add tests to the test execution.